# Alias (CNAME) record cannot be added to this DNS Name

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record, windows-dns

In Microsoft DNS, I'm trying to setup a simple DNS Alias (CNAME) pointing from domain.com to www.domain.com. I also want to forward www.domain.com to a specific IP.
In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
www.example.com. IN A 192.168.3.44
example.com. IN CNAME www.example.com.
```

When adding the CNAME I get the following Error:

"A new Record cannot be created. An alias (CNAME) record cannot be added to this DNS name. The DNS name conatins records that are incompatible with the CNAME record."

Why doesn't this work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it other way.

```
www.example.com IN CNAME example.com
```

This will create a subdomain `com/example` with an CNAME `www` that point to `example.com`

Can you try this?